# python bluetooth.BluetoothSocket connection No-route/Device or resource busy

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to my bluetooth devices using python, but I fail on very first step.
Most tutorial I found have code similar to this to connect.
I use MAC address from `hciconfig` - I guess this is mac of my only adapter.

```py
import bluetooth

for port in range(1, 11):
    try:
        s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
        s.connect(('00:1A:7D:DA:71:11', port))
        print("Connected")
        s.close()
    except OSError as err:
        print(f"Error connecting to {port}", err)
```

If run this above it will fail with `„Device or resource busy”`

If I use `s.connect('')` it fails with `„Device or resource busy”`.

I can use this adapter through `bluetoothctl` and other managers.

I have multiple devices working on it. So it is detected correctly by OS.

What is wrong here. How can I connect to my adapter using Python?

Comment: I faced the same problem ("Device or resource busy" when trying to connect to a RFCOMM server). For me it seems the cause was that the bluetooth settings UI was opened in the background, which forced the bluetooth device into scan mode. Trying to manually disable scan mode with `bluetoothctl` and then `scan off` resulted in `Failed to stop discovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed`. But when I closed the bluetooth settings UI, scanning stopped and the RFCOMM client connects reliably now.